# REST request to JAVA Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, rest

I have some JavaScript which I want to perform a REST Request (GET) to my servlet.
The format of the record I want to send is in the following format ...

```
/id1/vara/varb/varc/timedelta1,timedelta2,timedelta3,....,timedeltaN/
```

So basically there would be 5 attributes in each record I send. I need to batch these up - I'm sending multiple records in a single GET Request. My Get URL might look a little like the following.

```
myservletname/id1/vara/varb/varc/timedelta1,timedelta2,timedelta3/id2/vara/varb/varc/timedelta1,timedelta2,timedelta3/id3/vara/varb/varc/timedelta1,timedelta2,timedelta3/
```

I'm aware on the limit of around 2000 chars in the URL String so to keep things safe I'll ensure the length of the URL is less than this.
In the above example 3 records were sent to the servlet.

I'm wondering how I might process these on the server end. Havent really worked with REST before in Java. What do I need to do on the server end to process these URLs to extract the data ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered implementing your RESTful service using a JAX-RS framework such as Jersey?  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically

```
public class RestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String uri = request.getPathInfo();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*/"
        );
        Matcher m = p.matcher(uri);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String id = m.group(1);
            String vara = m.group(2);
            String varb = m.group(3);
            String deltas = m.group(4);

            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a very good model for how to do it, but it is simple and understandable for someone not familiar with Servlets

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAX-RS or Restlets instead of a servlet

Comment: U r welcome! I used Restlets in a GAE application and I found them to be really good. I couldn't use the JAX-RS on GAE at that time. JAX-RS is also good. It depends on what do you prefer. I like them both.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider using `POST` instead of `GET` for this. REST (and URLs) weren't designed for this purpose.